# open a win32diskimager-imported file on Windows

Tags: linux, filesystem, image, windows, backup

I have a raspberry pi. I did a backup by importing an image with win32diskimager. Is there any way to open this imported image and explore the filesystem in it? I'm on Windows 8, but Windows can't mount this image. It says, that the image is broken.

Are there any tools to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ext3 emulators for Windows. You could google or ask on a Windows or Linux Forum.

The best option would be to install a Linux Virtual Machine on Windows. VirtualBox is a free VM, and there are other popular emulators.

Probably the easiest would be to boot from a Linux live CD.

Comment: ok thank you :D the easiest way was to open this image on another linux system... :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a Linux machine?  This is pretty easy to access if you do.

Another option: If you have another Raspberry Pi, you could try accessing it with a USB card reader on the Raspberry Pi.